# In Python: How to run code atomic with out interruption?

Tags: python, synchronization, locking, atomic, critical-section

I saw already discussions about the synchronised question: How to prevent two threads entering the same section of code? They introduce some kind of synchronised decorator like in Java.

But that is not my problem. I would like to run a few lines of code at once. The Python interpreter shall not switch to another thread in between those lines of code. Maybe "without context switching" is the right description. Other threads shall wait until the python interpreter has completed the specified lines. And afterwards it can decide again to stop the execution of the current thread and excecute another thread for a while.

Is there a way to do that?
Something like this:

```
with atomic_lock:
    do_stuff()
    # no context switch here - executed directly after another
    do_other_stuff()
```

What I would like to do:

I would like to loop through the keys in a dictionary. The for loop fails if the dictionary is changed while the loop is executing. For example if a key is added. That happens on many other places in my code. So my idea was to prevent any other code from executing while the for loop is executed.
But maybe there is a different solution? Can I get a lock on that dictionary?

Comment: What you're asking for is called a "critical section", mutual exclusion so only one thread can be running a block of code.  Usually you get that by locking, since most hardware doesn't support a large set of operations as one atomic transaction, and presumably Python doesn't let you take advantage of hardware transactional memory anyway.  IDK if CPython might let you have multiple statements keep the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) locked, instead of releasing and re-acquiring between every operation.

Comment: What's the point in not allowing context switching? Is making the code transactional not sufficient?

Comment: Terminology: "atomic" (and the [atomic] tag) applies to operations on (a set of) data, not to code.  e.g. you can say a database transaction is atomic (either fully happens or doesn't at all), but you wouldn't say the functions inside the DBM are "atomic".  Mutual-exclusion via locking can give atomicity for access to some data, if all threads respect the lock.  You haven't shown what sort of thing you're trying to make atomic, and are really just asking about how to achieve mutual exclusion.

Comment: So here is my use case: I have a dictionary. I would like to make some operation on that dictionary that involves iterating through the keys. The for loop fails if the dictionary is changed while iterating. For example a key is added. There are many places in the code where that dictionary is changed. The simplest solution I imagined is to say the interpreter: just don't execute other code while you are in that for loop. But even if simple it don't seems that this is possible to implement.

Comment: I explicitly don't ask for a section of code that can only be run by one thread at the time. I ask for a section of code that can not be interrupted. So no other code can be run while this section is executed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Atomic means not dividable. And I am asking for a not dividable section of code. So in my understanding the tag atomic is correct here.

Comment: Yes, that's the etymology.  The actual usage in computing applies to operations / transactions, like in your case reading (and using) the keys of a dictionary.  At least that's my understanding; I think the usage to describe a block of code as uninterruptible is non-standard.  Especially with an implicit assumption of single-threaded execution, since not context-switching only excludes other threads from doing things if they can't already be running on other *cores* of a multi-core machine. (That's how CPython works for single bytecode operations because of the GIL.)

Comment: So the answer is: The way I tried to solve the problem is not possible. And I have to edit every line where I use this dictionary. I need to aquire a lock.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: That is not possibele yet.
The only possible way is to work with locks, because that is the only suitable thing that is implemented in the python interpreter.